# Deprecated: mysql_connect(): ERROR

Tags: php, mysql

I don't know what I'm doing wrong but I receive this error:-

> Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and
>   will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in
>   C:\wamp\www\includes\config.php on line 7

How can I fix this?

```
<?php
$mysql_hostname = "localhost";
$mysql_user = "bootstrapadmin";
$mysql_password = "";
$mysql_database = "bootstrap";

$bd = mysql_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password) or die("Mate you fucked something up!");
mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $bd) or die("Mate you fucked something up!");
?>
```

Now I'm running into the problem with my login page

```
Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\wamp\www\login.php on line 12
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0012  140512  {main}( )   ..\login.php:0
2   0.0079  149352  mysqli_query ( )    ..\login.php:12

( ! ) Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in C:\wamp\www\login.php on line 13
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0012  140512  {main}( )   ..\login.php:0
2   0.0960  149752  mysql_num_rows ( )  ..\login.php:13

<?php

session_start();
include("includes/config.php");

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    //username and password sent from form
    $myusername = addslashes($_POST['username']);
    $mypassword = md5(addslashes($_POST['password']));

    $sql = "SELECT userid FROM tbl_users WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
    $result = mysqli_query($sql);
    $count = mysql_num_rows($result);

    // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
    if ($count == 1) {
        //$session_register("myusername");
        $_SESSION['login_admin'] = $myusername;
        header("location: http://localhost/admin/");
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Here is a picture of what it is doing.... https://gyazo.com/e2b3e6a5c554ead07cca019e3c7be516

Comment: move toward `mysqli_*` or `PDO`. `mysql_*` are deprecated library now.

Comment: if you are using PHP 5.5 and above you will get this Warning. In PHP 7 mysql_ is removed totally, afaik, so there you probably will be getting a fatal error. Move to other solutions, like PDO, mysqli_ or others

Comment: explore : http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: You either adapt to the latest ones (PDO/Mysqli) for the better or use old versions/methods/platforms for the worse.

Comment: Now I'm running into an error with my login page...

Comment: I've updated the post of the new error I'm running into...

Answer (score 1):

`mysql_*` functions are no longer supported. You can use `mysqli_*` functions instead. For eg:

```
<?php
$mysql_hostname = "localhost";
$mysql_user = "bootstrapadmin";
$mysql_password = "";
$mysql_database = "bootstrap";

$bd = mysqli_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password) or die("Mate you messed something up!");
mysqli_select_db($mysql_database, $bd) or die("Mate you messed something up!");
?>
```

Comment: https://gyazo.com/ef49a7c8a03bb4df9604608e92519b92

Answer (score 0):

Have you searched for MySQLi or PDO? 
The old `mysql_*` methods are deprecated and will be removed in the upcoming versions of PHP.

In my opinion PDO is the best way to go, but just converting to MySQLi should be sufficient. Just research a little and use one of these newer techniques.

For MySQLi basically just change the two last lines to:

```
$connection = mysqli_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password) or die("Mate you fucked something up!");

mysqli_select_db($connection, $mysql_database) or die("Mate you fucked something up!");
```

(Added the "i" after "mysql" / also switched parameters on db-selection)

More information on MySQLi: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_mysqli.asp

Comment: I receive gyazo.com/ef49a7c8a03bb4df9604608e92519b92

Comment: yeah, we had the parameters in the wrong order, please try again with updated code

Comment: I did let me see if I have to update wampserver since I'm using it to beta test before uploading to my website.

Comment: No, everything was up to date. I had a friend look over my code and he said basically all the code that I had coded was old and barely supported anymore so me and him basically rewrote it.